# How to dynamically create a lot of data for INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P parameterized unit tests

Tags: c++, visual-c++, googletest

I need help with INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(prefix, test, testing::ValuesIn(container)).

Running VS 2022 and latest google test ("Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn" version="1.8.1.5")

The problem is, INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P appears to ****only** use the data in the container at compile time**. I've tried everything to add more at runtime, before any tests run, without success (e.g., using SetUpTestSuite and SetUpEnvironment as mentioned [google test docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#global-set-up-and-tear-down)

This is actually a big problem. I have a lot of test data, too much to embed in the code without dramatically slower build times and warnings about “too much stack data, use the heap”.

The sample code below shows the problem. Allocate two global vectors, one populated at compile time the other populated at runtime. Even though testing::Environment::SetUp is populating one vector with additional data, INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P is only using the contents found at compile time.

Am I missing something stupid simple? Is there another way to load a container so INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P will use it?

```
    TestData.h
    struct TestData { std::string str_;};
    
    extern std::vector<TestData>*  g_data_in_code;
    extern std::vector<TestData>*  g_data_in_file;


    TestData.cpp

    //First approach, global pointer and initializer list for data 
    std::vector<TestData>* g_data_in_code  = new std::vector<TestData>
    {
        TestData{"1"}, TestData{"2"}
    };

    //Second approch, global pointer and load data during Environment SetUp 
    std::vector<TestData>* g_data_in_file = new std::vector<TestData>
    {
        TestData{"3"}//added one element so google test will not skip empty container
    };

    void LoadTestData(std::vector<TestData>* test_data)
    {
    ...just reads a text file line by line adding N number of TestData...
    }
```

As recommended in google test docs, use my own main() instead of using gtest_main() and subclass Environment and implement SetUp to load test data prior to google test Environment start up.

```
class MyTestEnvironment : public ::testing::Environment
{
public:
    ~MyTestEnvironment() override {}

    void SetUp() override    
    {
        LoadTestData(g_data_in_file);  //N more elements added
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    auto* env = testing::AddGlobalTestEnvironment(new MyTestEnvironment);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The actual Test.cc is simply

```
class ParamTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<TestData>{};

TEST_P(ParamTest,OneParamTest) {
    EXPECT_TRUE(1 == 1);
    //Interestingly, g_data_in_file->size() is N, but only 1 test 
    //will run because, again, at compile time it contained 1 TestData not N 
}

//3 passing tests
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(TestsFromCode, ParamTest, testing::ValuesIn(*g_data_in_code));

//1 passing test, instead of N passing tests (the number loaded by SetUp)
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(TestsFromFile, ParamTest, testing::ValuesIn(*g_data_in_file));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator expressions (including parameters to the generator) are evaluated in `InitGoogleTest()`. Therefore, it is necessary to read the data and put it to `g_data_in_file` before `InitGoogleTest()` is called in `main` function. And `Environment::SetUp()` is called only from `RUN_ALL_TESTS()`. So, it's too late to read the data for the parameterized test in `Environment::SetUp()`.

But you can change a little bit the `LoadTestData()` function:

```cpp
...
std::vector<TestData> LoadTestData()
{
    std::vector<TestData> test_data;
    //...just reads a text file line by line adding N number of TestData...
    return test_data;
}
...
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(TestsFromFile, ParamTest, testing::ValuesIn(LoadTestData()));
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Egor. Calling LoadTestData before InitGoogleTest() fixes my issue.